# Function Pointer - Passing reference to self

Tags: java

Hi is it possible to implement a function pointer in JAVA
I am trying to do something like this

```
void methodA
{
  try
   {
   }
  catch(Exception E)
   {
    methodB(Pass the function pointer pointing to methodA)
   }
}

void methodB(fp some_function_pointer)
{
   call some_function_pointer
}
```

Comment: are you trying to re-implement a method from the beginning once an exception is encountered in it?

Comment: yes. Thats what i am trying to do

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can pass the object itself:

```
public class Foo {
    void methodA() {
        try {
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            bar.methodB(this)
        }
    } 
}

public class Bar {
    void methodB(Foo someFoo) {
        someFoo.methodA();
    } 
}
```

If you want to be able to pass any method, then wrap this method into a Runnable or Callable for example:

```
public class Foo {
    void methodA() {
        try {
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            bar.methodB(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Foo.this.methodA();
                }
            });
        }
    } 
}

public class Bar {
    void methodB(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    } 
}
```

Comment: What happens if they are in the same class ?

Answer (score 1):

In java without using a reflection its impossible to define a function pointer.

You can use reflection (see class **java.lang.reflect.Method**) to mimic this behavior to some extent, but in general this code sound weird (although maybe I don't get something ;))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass function pointers. The easiest way to do this is to package the method in an interface and pass an object that implements the interface instead of a function reference.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is first class functions. Your example requires `methodA` to be first class function, so let's change it to that.

The following class represents a first class function with arity 0 (a formal way of saying it takes no arguments).

```
abstract class F0<A> {
  public abstract A apply(); 
}
```

Using it, your code can be rewritten as:

```
F0<Void> methodA = new F0<Void>() {
  @Override
  public Void apply() {
    try {
      // failable actions
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      methodB(methodA);
    }
    return null;
  }
};

void methodB(F0<Void> methodA) {
  methodA.apply();
}
```

---

**Tangent:**

I admit the above code looks a bit too gnarly, but IDEs such as IntelliJ IDEA provide what they call "closure folding" that makes such code look a little nicer. See for example what this code looks like in my IDE:

[image: Were you hoping to find a joke in this tooltip?]